# (is my answer correct?) total differential of the function $u=\int _0^xe^{-s^2}ds\:$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

if $u=\int _0^xe^{-s^2}ds\:$ i want to find $\frac{dx}{du}$

if i solve this through $\frac{d}{dx}\int _0^xe^{-s^2}ds=f\left(x,v\right)\frac{dv}{dx}-f\left(x,u\right)\frac{du}{dx}+\int _0^x\frac{∂f}{∂x}ds$, which is Leibniz' rule, i get

$\frac{d}{dx}\int _0^xe^{-s^2}ds=e^{-x^2}\left(1\right)-\left(1\right)\left(0\right)+\int _0^x\left(0\right)ds=e^{-x^2}$

what i found is $\frac{du}{dx}$ rather than $\frac{dx}{du}$. Is it correct if i treat them as reciprocal so the answer would be $e^{x^2}$? or my calculation is incorrect since in the first place? thank you so much for your time.

note : it has nothing to do with homework or school, i'm just curious!

Comment: You're somewhat correct. The inverse function theorem tells you that $$\frac{dx}{du} = \frac{1}{\frac{du}{dx}}$$ however you must evaluate at the appropriate points. $\dfrac{dx}{du}$ is a function of $u$ whereas $\dfrac{du}{dx}$ is a function of $x$ so you must apply an inverse somewhere to get the final answer. That said, I do not think there is a nice answer because there is no easy way to write $x$ as a function of $u$.

Comment: so according to the inverse function, it's ok if i write this as $\frac{dx}{du}=\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dx}\int _0^xe^{-s^2}ds\:}=e^{x^2}$, right? btw thank you so much. :) @CameronWilliams

Comment: As I said, you're almost correct. $\frac{dx}{du}$ must be a function of $u$ but what you have is a function of $x$ ($e^{x^2}$) so you have to write $x$ in terms of $u$.

Comment: if i change the upper limit of the integral as $u$, so $\frac{d}{du}\int _0^ue^{-s^2}ds=e^{-u^2}\:$ this time $x$ in terms of $u$. How? @CameronWilliams